# SvelteKit - Nested Prop Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'whatever')

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, flowbite-svelte

Simply I don't get it. I store fetch result in writable store and retrieve those data, but I got undefined error when I want to use nested json data (school) see below. Why?

```
    <p>item: {$data.item}</p>           <--- OK!
    <p>address: {$data.address}</p>     <--- OK!
    <p>school: {$data.city.school}</p>  <--- PROBLEM: Undefined. Why? simple nested json...

Json structure:

{
"item": "whatever",
"address": "address",
"city": {
"school": "school"
}

}
```

```
export default function fetchData() {
    const loading = writable(false)
    const error = writable(false)
    const data = writable({})
    let clear;
    async function getData() {
        loading.set(true)
        error.set(false)
        try {
            const response = await fetch('http://endpoint')
            data.set(await response.json())
        } catch(e) {
            error.set(e)
        }
        loading.set(false)
    }
  
  clearInterval(clear)
  clear = setInterval(getData, 5000)

    return [ data, loading, error, getData]
}
```

In svelte file:

```
<script>
    import snapshotStore from '../stores/dataStore';
    const [data, loading, error, getData] = dataStore();
</script>

<p>item: {$data.item}</p>           
<p>address: {$data.address}</p>    
<p>school: {$data.city.school}</p> <--- Problem, undefined.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The store is initialized like this:

```js
const data = writable({})
```

Any access like `$data.item` will *initially* just return `undefined` and not cause errors, but `$data.city.school` will try access the `school` property on `undefined`.

Either make the access safe (e.g. `$data.city?.school` or wrap things in `{#if}`), or initialize the store in a way that allows for this access without error, e.g.

```js
const data = writable({ city: { } })
```

`{#if}` guards based on `$loading` and `$error` should also work, if the API is guaranteed to send the correct JSON (i.e. the `city` object always exists).

```html
{#if $loading}
  ...
{:else if $error}
  ...
{:else}
  <p>item: {$data.item}</p>           
  <p>address: {$data.address}</p>    
  <p>school: {$data.city.school}</p>
{/if}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! $data.city?.school works like a charm! Can you please elaborate the #if solution?  {#if store} .... {/if}? or something else? Btw. the most confusing part was when I access to $data.item, it does not return undefined, but proper value. This issue occured when I access nested json data.

Comment: For `#if` you need to check whether city exists, so `{#if $data.city} access school here {/if}`.

Comment: If everything is wrapped in `{#if $loading == false && $error == false} ... {/if}` you also should not run into issues (if the sent JSON contains the expected full object hierarchy).

Comment: I will check this solution instead of ?. Thank you!!!